# Как правильно связать модель с другими моделями по ID?

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

Подскажите, у меня есть модель ContentTag (id, tag_code)

Также есть еще модель Content (id, content_tag_id, content)

Как реализовать связь у Content с другими моделями, чтобы потом по значениям этих связей вызывать нужный Content

Например, такой функцией:

getContent('text_1', ['Brand' => 1, 'Model' => 92), где text1 - это tag_code у ContentTag, а значения в массиве - айдишники моделей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации](https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) `laravel`, все написано про связи.

Вам надо наглядно понять все связи, к примеру (`hasOne`, `hasMany`)

В вашем примере видно что у каждого `Content` может быть только один `ContentTag`.

Значит в модели `Content` связь будет выглядить так.

```
public function contentTag(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(ContentTag::class, 'id', 'content_tag_id');
}
```

А обратная связь как видно `hasMany`. Тоесть один `ContentTag` может иметь много `Content`.
И связь в нем будет выглядить следующим образом.

```
public function contents(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Content::class, 'content_tag_id', 'id');
}
```

А запрос в вашем случае будет выглядеть так.

```
ContentTag::where('tag_code', 'text1')->with('contents')->get();
```

Comment: Content представляет собой модель, содержащую текст/изображение, является дополнением к ContentTag.

Content у ContentTag может быть много.

ContentTag регистрирует отпределенную единицу контента, имеет свой уникальный код для последующего вызова через него, например, seo_text_to_brand.

В свою очередь Content, принадлежащий ContentTag через внешний ключ content_tag_id, должен иметь привязки к неограниченному количеству других моделей. Например, к Brand.id=1, DeviceModel.id=22, это абстрактно.

Comment: И если я вызываю функцию getContent('seo_text_to_brand', ['Brand' => 1, 'DeviceModel' => 22), у меня должен появляться текст Content, у которого удовлетворена указанная в функции связь.

Comment: @DaMarkuzz Тогда измените вопрос. И дайте подробноую информацию про все модели. Вы здесь в вопросе упамянули только 2 модели. Но во всяком случае аналагичным способом можно привязать и другие ваши модели.